# Get records for particular day of the week in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES cluster that has some summarized numerical data such that there is exactly 1 record per day. I want to write a query that will return the documents for a specific day of the week. For example, all records for Tuesdays. Currently I am doing this by getting all records for the required date range and then filtering out the ones for the day that I need. Is there a way to do that with a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a script like this:

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc.my_date.value.dayOfWeek == 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're going to run this query often, you would be probably better off creating another field `dayOfWeek` in your document that contains the day of the week that you can then easily query using a term query. It would be more efficient than a script.